# Why does apt think this package isn't installed?

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.04

If I run `apt list python-py` I see the package `python-py` (which I just installed, via `sudo apt install python-py`, thinking it was something other than what it is):

```
Listing... Done
python-py/bionic,bionic 1.5.2-1 all
```

Attempting to uninstall this package by running `sudo apt remove python-py`, I am greeted by the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'python-py' is not installed, so not removed
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

`apt` seems to be contradicting itself, what's going on?

Comment: Please edit your question to clearly explain how you installed `python-py`. If possible, locate the install terminal log in /var/log/apt/term.log, and paste that entire install session (not the whole log).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `apt list` command doesn't check just installed packages. It checks the database of all known packages from all known sources, whether installed or not.

Here's an example of `apt list` of an installed package:

```
$ apt list python3
Listing... Done
python3/cosmic-updates,now 3.6.7-1~18.10 amd64 [installed]
```

`apt list` will clearly tell you which packages are [installed].

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to AskUbuntu SE!
I think you are mistaken about python-py being installed.
apt list will list all the packages available (as said by user535733)
Here's a screenshot to assure you :)

[image]